# Python - varible name change

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary or list of some sort to show the names:

```
Bubblegum_1
Bubblegum_2
Bubblegum_3
Bubblegum_4
Bubblegum_5
Bubblegum_6
```

How to I do a line of code that would dynamically change the name number for me without me touching it?

The desire would be to only have Bubblegum_ + something that can help me do this without me typing it in manually.

Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear where the problem is. Could you show an example of what you're starting out with, and explain what you want to end up with? Are you able to use dictionaries or lists at all? If so: can you explain a rule that tells you what the keys of the dictionary should be, or how long the list should be? Where does the data come from, and what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your variables in form of `Keys` of a `Dictionary`.

```
data = {}

for i in range(1,10):
  data["Bubblegum_"+str(i)] = i*2

data
```

Your `data` variable will look something like this :

```
{
 'Bubblegum_1': 2,
 'Bubblegum_2': 4,
 'Bubblegum_3': 6,
 'Bubblegum_4': 8,
 'Bubblegum_5': 10,
 'Bubblegum_6': 12,
 'Bubblegum_7': 14,
 'Bubblegum_8': 16,
 'Bubblegum_9': 18
}
```

And finally you access your variables value like this :

```
data['Bubblegum_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 15#or amount of strings you want
bubblegum = list()
for i in range(num):
     bubblegum.append('Bubblegum_' + str(i))
print(bubblegum)
```